# removing item from copied list also removes from original

Tags: android

```
public static void printList(ArrayList<Col> list, String place)
{
    ArrayList<Col> list2 = list;
    int count=0;
    float r,g,b;
    while(!list2.isEmpty())
    {
        r = list2.get(count).getR();
        g = list2.get(count).getG();
        b = list2.get(count).getB();
        list2.remove(0);
        Log.i(place+": "+count + "", "R: "+r+"   G: "+g+"   B: "+b);
    }
}
```

this method is removing all the items from my original list for some reason..
i'm thinking maybe the way i duplicate the list is wrong, but i couldnt find the right way.

Comment: try `ArrayList<Col> list2 = new ArrayList<Col>(list);`

Comment: thanks! thhat solved my problem! can you please explain why this happens? and please post it as an answer so i can mark it answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ArrayList is an object:

```
ArrayList<Col> list2 = list;
```

is a soft copy. It only copies a reference to the same ArrayList object.

In Java you can clone an object like so:

```
ArrayList<Col> list2 = (ArrayList<Col>)list.clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code before assigning the value:

```
ArrayList<Col> list2 = new ArrayList<Col> ();
```

Comment: I am using cell phone, so can not format answer@Muhammed Refaat

Comment: Only a dumb person will do that @Mitch Dart

Answer (score 0):

USE

> ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList(list);

INSTEAD OF

> ArrayList list2 = list;